# communication Issue between ASP.net and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following scenario-

User may enter text in any language in the text box and  need to store it in my database along with language name. Following is the code for this on `button Update`

```vb
Dim conStr As String = "Dsn=search;database=search;description=search;option=0;port=0;server=localhost;uid=root;CharacterSet=UTF8;"
Dim s As String = txtLanguage.Text '<----"音読み現代仮名遣い人名用漢字"
mySQL = "INSERT INTO multi_language(language, characters)" & _
        " VALUES ('Japanese', '" & s & "')"
con.ConnectionString = conStr
con.Open()
cmd = New OdbcCommand(mySQL, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

**[image]screen short for running the query**

after clicking button the text in the `Textbox` becomes `'??????'`
 and the data inserted in the data base is like the following

```
  Language     |     characters
  --------------------------
  Japanese     |      ?????
```

**My table structure is**

```
CREATE TABLE multi_language
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
language VARCHAR(30),
characters TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

when i execute the query directly in the query browser then it will executed properly,

**whats wrong with my coding? what i need to add to get proper result?**

This is the screenshot for the comparison of insert from the [image: asp.net page and query browser]

Comment: the language input is Unicode therefore you have to change data type for characters column to `NVARCHAR`

Comment: its inserted in the database when i executed the query in the database as: `INSERT INTO multi_language(language, characters)
VALUES ('Japanese', '音読み現代仮名遣い人名用漢字');` but i can't executed it from the asp.net

Comment: you cannot add Japaneses language in text format directly   see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-table.html

Comment: @ Rashid : its working fine for me when i execute the insert query through query browser, but not from the asp.net

Comment: Can you try with `\u....` values instead of unicode characters? Probably the encoding for the compiler is not set properly to support unicode characters.

Comment: Pretty sure it has to do with passing UTF8 encoded string from asp.net.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also suffering from a similar situation, i solved it in a different way as follows:

while **inserting** Use your Query as  :

```
Dim s As String = txtLanguage.Text '<----"音読み現代仮名遣い人名用漢字"
mySQL = "INSERT INTO multi_language(language, characters)" & _
        " VALUES ('Japanese', '" & encodeUTF(s) & "')"
```

**Encode the string before inserting**

```
Public Function encodeUTF(ByVal inputString As String) As String '<-- function for encoding the input string
        Dim byt() As Byte = uni.GetBytes(inputString)
        encodeUTF = ""
        For Each b As Byte In byt
            encodeUTF &= b & ","
        Next
        Trim(Replace(encodeUTF, ",", ""))
End Function
```

**decode the string before retriving**

```
Public Function decodeUTF(ByVal inputString As String) As String '<-- function for decoding the input string
    Dim strs() As String
    strs = inputString.Split(",").ToArray
    Dim temp(strs.Length) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To strs.Length - 2
        temp(i) = Byte.Parse(strs(i))
    Next
    decodeUTF = uni.GetString(temp)
    decodeUTF = decodeUTF.Substring(0, Len(decodeUTF) - 1)
End Function
```

While Retrieving this text to a text box you can use your query as :

```
 mySQL = "Select language, characters from multi_language"
 Reader = objdb.GetDataReader(mySQL)'<--- is a class function which returns the datareader
 If Reader.HasRows = True Then
    Reader.Read()
    txtlang.Text = objOdbcDataReader.Item("language")'<--- display the selected language
    txtchar.Text = objOdbcDataReader.Item("characters ")'<--- display the selected characters
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this proposed solution,

If your application want to save data in to database in multiple language, make sure your database stores data in UTF-8 and also the connection to your database is in UTF-8 (commonly people forget this).

Make sure to Execute this query when establishing a connection:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

In Your application end, where user input data, set the accept-charset attribute on your forms.

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Set appropriate meta tags for your site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or Serve your sites with an appropriate HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

So overall the problem is, everything is not in `UTF-8`, If you keep everything in `UTF-8`, usually don't need to worry about anything.

Refer [Strategy for supporting unicode & multi language in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085093/strategy-for-supporting-unicode-multi-language-in-php5/)

[Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80-using-php-and-mysql/1198713#1198713)

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you should use parametrized query (which anyway is always a better choice than string concatenation, which is susceptible to sql injection)

modify your query to use parameters (I am not sure if for mysql the @param is correct syntax):

```
"INSERT INTO multi_language(language, characters) VALUES ('Japanese',  @val)"
```

then add parameter to your query:

```
cmd = New OdbcCommand(mySQL, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", txtLanguage.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```